# Tense of the phrase using 'familiar with'

Tags: phrases, expressions

The phrase 'I am familiar with' (brand/style/speech/opinion) etc doesn't seem to follow the tense/verb rules.  It appears to start off with present continuous but it doesn't use a present participle (ing) so I'm doing a lot of headscratching...and staring blankly...can anyone help please?  (Soon...I need to explain to a student!!)  Thanks.

Comment: *Familiar* is an adjective, extended to what one is familiar with. "I am familiar with London" has the same structure as "I am tired" (or even "I am tired of London"). It's simple present tense.

Comment: The presence of an auxiliary verb _am_ is not a mark of the continuous; the continuous requires _be_, but so does the passive, and so do predicate nouns and predicate adjectives. The mark of the continuous is _be_ plus the active participle (_-ing_ form); if _be_ is followed by something else, it's not the continuous.